# Java Passing ArrayList into Function to pull data from Object

Tags: java, arraylist

So I want to calculate the average salary,being the 2nd parameter in the Bank Object.I already have my getters and setters.
Thank you :)

```
int avgSal(WHAT GOES HERE)
{

    int Avg = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {


    }

    return Avg;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Bank A = new Bank("Tom",23000,1);
    Bank B = new Bank("Mary",43000,9);
    Bank C = new Bank("Brigid",56000,11);
    Bank D = new Bank("Alison",49000,4);



    List<Bank> list = new ArrayList<Bank>();
    list.add(A); 
    list.add(B);
    list.add(C);
    list.add(D);





}
```

Comment: Replace `WHAT GOES HERE` with `List<Bank> banks`?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev This is not a site where you post _any_ questions without showing any effort to awnser them. :D

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? I'm not sure if you are asking how to acces the field `salary` of an object inside a list? Or do you just want to know how to pass an `ArrayList<Bank>` to the method `avgSal()`?

Comment: Are you using Java8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an `ArrayList<Bank>` object to your `avgSal()` method, then calculate the average.

```
int avgSal(List<Bank> banks) {
    int avg = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < banks.size(); i++) {
        avg += banks.get(i).getSalery();
    }

    avg /= banks.size();

    return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method return value needs to be double to save floating numbers

```
double avgSal(List<Bank> list) {
    double Avg = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        Avg += list.get(i).getSalery();
    }
    return Avg/list.size();
}
```